# UISlider Change values in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uislider

I have 4 values in `UISlider`. I want that when the slider value changes it should display the following values

```
  if (slider.value==0)
  {
      label.text="5";
  }
  else if(slider.value==1)
  {
      label.text="10"
  }
  else
  {
      label.text="15";
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a connection to the UISlider's ***Value Changed*** event in Interface Builder. You can implement a method such as:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    if (slider.value < 1) {
        self.label.text = @"5";
    }
    else if (slider.value < 2) {
        self.label.text = @"10";
    }
    else {
        self.label.text = @"15";
    }
}
```

If you want to hook up the event programatically, you can use:

```
[self.mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Note that the slider will be reporting values with decimal places, so your cases where the value equals an integer are rare. Change the logic to use less-than checks as shown above.

Comment: yes i am doing like this but it is showing alwyas else condition

Answer (score 1):

```
if (slider.value == 0) {
```

and

```
if (slider.value == 1) {
```

is wrong - you can't compare floating-point numbers using the == (and != ) operators - because they're not exact values. You should do something like this:

```
if (slider.value < 0.001) {
```

and

```
if (slider.value > 0.999) {
```

Comment: @Nitish that's fine also (since it includes the possibility for < and >), but it's longer to write out.